# Why is this simple code returning `none`?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do this codefights task:

*Given a sequence of integers as an array, determine whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by removing no more than one element from the array.*

So here's my code:

```
def almostIncreasingSequence(sequence):
def checa(sequence):
    cont = 0
    copia1 = copia2 = sequence
    for i in range(len(sequence)-1):
        while(cont == 0):
            if(sequence[i] >= sequence[i+1]):
                del(copia1[i])
                del(copia2[i+1])
                cont += 1
    if(all(copia1[j] < copia1[j+1] for j in range(len(copia1)-1)) == True):
        return True
    elif(all(copia2[j] < copia2[j+1] for j in range(len(copia2)-1)) == True):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I can't see my flaws here and it's returning `None` every single time.

Comment: where is your `return` ?

Comment: What is `Null`? Can't say I'm familiar with that value.

Comment: @Kevin haha good catch.

Comment: I added the `return` still getting `none`.

Comment: Someone please come back to my question. I added the `return` as asked but no one will answer it now...

Comment: Hi. if you ask for help, you should take care to show all relevant information and the exact code in your question. We can't see what see on your computer, this question is all we know. We can't guess the missing information. First you forgot the return statement, now after editing  there are two `def...:` lines, which also doesn't make much sense. And you never showed the code that calls your function and the input data. That makes it quite difficult to answer. Please update your question, in the state it is now, it's hard to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You did not include a `return` statement, thus your function will always return `None`

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", and the bullet point regarding questions which "have already been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I usually never answer duplicate. Honestly, I did not know that this answer even existed. My bad and thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I thought `all` would return true/false so there would be no need for `return`?

Comment: I added the `return` in edit.